# How to pass hex chars regex in string assertion

Tags: javascript, regex, webdriver-io

I am using javascript with webDriverIO for automated test and in my assertion, one of the substrings is a dynamic value which keeps changing to hex chars every time I run my test therefore want to cover this value with a regex pattern

For an example:

```
expect(await browser.testFunction()).to.match(/conda[\\/]envs[\\/]f0b3e3538b395cf003cf5128ce26[\\/]bin[\\/]python3/)
```

Where **f0b3e3538b395cf003cf5128ce26** is project id which keep changing in a given pattern.

In above i want to cover f0b3e3538b395cf003cf5128ce26 with regex pattern **[0-9a-fA-F]+**

I am trying this like:

```
expect(await browser.testFunction()).to.match(/conda[\\/]envs[\\/][0-9a-fA-F]+[\\/]bin[\\/]python3/)
```

This throw error "**re.exec is not a function**"

Can someone help with how to apply regex pattern correctly ?

Comment: Tag your question with the language you are using. And where is `re.exec` being called?

Comment: @Booboo Edited my post inline with your suggestion. Not calling re.exec anywhere but it surface in the error log

Comment: Now I have to shout: **What language are you using?** JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks that the issue you're experiencing might be related to using a regex literal inside the .match() function, and not the regex pattern itself. To fix this issue, I think you should use the RegExp constructor to create a regex object with your desired pattern. Here is an example I have made to show you how you could do this:

```
const regexPattern = new RegExp('conda[\\\\/]envs[\\\\/][0-9a-fA-F]+[\\\\/]bin[\\\\/]python3');


expect(await browser.testFunction()).to.match(regexPattern);
```